# openconnect password and cookie input

Tags: command-line, passwords, openconnect

After 2-3 day search and work now i hope you can help ...
I want to use from openconnect in my program and for auth have 2 solution
1 - use from user and pass (but pass dont have any option for command line and only with standard input can input pass)
2 - used from cookie (but openconnect not work with cookie for me !)

For Cookie i do this

-send user with post method to server 
-server ask for password 
-send password with post method to server 
-if all is ok and auth id = success  
-read header and get cookie

open command line and send ip and cookie to openconenct

and Error !

> Creating SSL connection failed

command line code

```
openconnect.exe vpn.server.ip --no-cert-check -C "webvpn=BPlUDg9oaTN2uQQ0DQvH7QopD3x5NahiCHQgTqKQ7KPJg38dSuvqLmYIo9Jskig; Secure,webvpnc=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; Secure,webvpnc=bu:/&p:t&iu:1/&sh:7350D46A8EE85D06&lu:/+CSCOT+/translation-table?textdomain%3DAnyConnect%26type%3Dmanifest&fu:profiles%2F/etc/ocserv/profile.xml&fh:6B5181182D2B5483FBB8D2AA1BCBACC9A70E2BA3; path=/; Secure"
```

for send user and pass with post method i use from C#

2 - for user and pass i do this work
use from command line for auto fill input with this code

```
type password | openconnect.exe vpn.server.ip -u username --no-cert-check
```

and

```
password | openconnect.exe vpn.server.ip -u username --no-cert-check
```

and

```
openconnect.exe vpn.server.ip -u username --no-cert-check < pas.txt
```

and again error !!!

> Password: ReadConsole() failed: The handle is invalid.

now i want to know whats wrong in my code ??

or have any better solution for accept cookie or auto fill input ?

if you have any idea please tell me.

thanks and kind regards.

[openconnect command line info](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/manual.html)

Answer (score 3):

In ubuntu you can use this:

```
openconnect --script ./vpnc.sh target-domain --no-cert-check -u username --passwd-on-stdin < pass.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: --no-cert-check  been removed, and then it asks a question about cert and i need to enter an answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Openconnect Autofill Username and Password

There is a trade-off between convenience and security. Autofill user and password is not recommended in terms of security.

In case you need the convenience to make an autoconnection using openconnect here is a simple example steps:

### Simple Steps Example

#### Create a plaintext password file

`mypass.txt`
contains only the password:

---

`mysupersecretpassword`

---

#### Create a script to call *openconnect*

`myscript.sh` contains two lines of command:

---

`openconnect --protocol=gp vpn.mycompany.com --user=abc123 --passwd-on-stdin < mypass.txt
./myscript.sh`

---

the second line `./myscript.sh` is intentionally added to make the script loop forever thus create a persistent VPN connection.

#### Make script executable

In terminal line:

`chmod +x myscript.sh`

#### Run your script

run your script with a `sudo` privilege

`sudo ./myscript.sh`

to exit the loop just press `CTRL + C`

### For More Security

For added security you can make the process not so simple:

1. put your script and password file in a protected/hidden directory that only `root` level user can access;
2. Encrypt the plaintext password file and make another script to decrypt and read the password for example using linux `gpg`, but you will still have to enter the encryption/decryption passphrase.

Comment: for those in rush and need a practical answer to implement, I have created `ovlauncher` [here](https://github.com/jansenicus/openconnect-vpn)